# Trying to access my website results in an ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT

Tags: apache2, webserver

I took a break over Christmas from developing a webapp and I have came back today to find that I am unable to access my website in my browser, or connect to it by an FTP Client or ping my website's IP address (Results in Requests Timed Out). My server is hosted on DigitalOcean. Obviously I cannot continue development because I am unable to render my changes or connect in general.

**Digital Ocean Droplet**

Digital Ocean Rebooted my Droplet (where my server is)
I got this email from Digital Ocean over Christmas:

“We’ve had to reboot your Droplet as a result of an issue with the physical node that hosts your Droplet. We will continue to investigate the health of this physical node to determine if this was an isolated or systemic issue.

No action is required on your part at this time and we apologize for any troubles this may have caused.”

My website is still down and my tickets have fallen on deaf ears from the folks at Digital Ocean.

**Issue**

ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT is the chrome error message. Before Christmas everything was working fine, in fact I'm very near completing development.

The issue is the same across browsers, ISPs, mobile networks etc.

**What I've tried:**

- Restarting Apache - Apache is running and active
- Rebooting my server - Rebooted successfully but no changes
- Checked UFW firewall rules - These haven't changed
- Enabled/Disabled firewall
- Pinging my websites IP - Results in timeouts
- Connecting with numerous FTP Clients (Filezilla, WinSCP etc.) -
  Results in timeouts
- It is not a DNS issue - There is no domain name yet, the IP address
  is being used in this development phase to navigate to the website.
- I am unable shh into the droplet.

**Suggestions**

Are there any other suggestions for actions that I can do to try to remedy this or find out what has caused the issue?

I can spin up another server if needs be but I really want to figure out what has actually happened so I can learn from it.

Thanks and Happy New Year.

Comment: You can increase the memory limit depending on what type of app it is? Enter site from phpmyadmin and deactivate plugins. Or Increase the PHP allocated memory. Digital Ocean has a recover droplet from snapshot. More info about the app please.

Comment: did it got fixed for you ?  How? I am stuck with this since a month